# How can I use a custom logging handler with django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to integrate logging with loki in my django app like this:

```
handler = logging_loki.LokiHandler(
    url="http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push",
    tags={"app": "django", "env": ENV},
    version="1",
)

LOGGING = {
      'version': 1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'formatters': {
       'standard': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(module)s} [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'standard',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', handler], # this doesnt work
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
        # 'name': ENV
    }
}
}
```

What do I need to change so that django uses this custom handler? I tried just referencing the handler object in the logging dict but that didn't need to be the right approach.

I also tried this:

```
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(handler)
```

but that's not sending any logs to loki

Comment: I've tried adding the handler variable to the `LOGGING` dict's default logger, I've tried disabling djangos logging config and doing it myself and I tried doing `handler.__dict__` and using that as a handler in the dict. None of this worked.

Comment: I also tried `logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)` in `settings.py` but that doesn't send anything to loki

Comment: You haven't shown us a key component which is the contents of your `LOGGING` setting. Have you actually [assigned the handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#examples) you've defined to any loggers? If not, then merely defining a handler won't do anything.

Comment: @solarissmoke I was trying to use the `addHandler` function but it's not working. I'll edit my OP with the LOGGING setting.

Comment: @ninesalt what `dictConfig` expects is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) and it's linked from django's doc. Solarismoke already posted a full answer so I won't duplicate it - just note that you might have gotten such an answer sooner if you had posted your full efforts right from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(module)s} [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'loki': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging_loki.LokiHandler',
            'url': "http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push",
            'tags' {"app": "django", "env": ENV},
            'version': "1",
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'loki'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, you have to:

1. Define you handler in the `handlers` dictionary in the `LOGGING` setting. The configuration here is used to specify the initialisation arguments for the handler.
2. Then assign this handler using its key (`loki` in the example I've given above) to the logger(s) you want it to handle.

Comment: I'm trying to add the handler to the default `django` logger as well so I did that by adding `'django': {'handlers': ['console', 'loki'], 'level': 'INFO'}` to `LOGGING` under the current logger but for some reason everything is logged twice (even with `disable_existing_loggers` set to `True`) any ideas?

Comment: I guess you have `'propagate': True` on the `django` logger? Change that to false on the `django` logger so that it doesn't propagate to the parent (`""`) logger.